# My app crashing everytime chashing when using renderscript

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I cant use renderscript. here is my logcat output.

```
10-28 14:23:24.557 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/RenderScript_jni: No GC methods
10-28 14:23:24.557 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/com.infasoftlanka.filter/lib/librsjni.so 0x42187db0
10-28 14:23:24.562 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/data/com.infasoftlanka.filter/lib/librsjni.so 0x42187db0
10-28 14:23:24.562 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter V/RenderScript_jni: RS compat mode
10-28 14:23:24.562 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/com.infasoftlanka.filter/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x42187db0
10-28 14:23:24.572 5714-5716/com.infasoftlanka.filter D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 212K, 15% free 9572K/11143K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 32ms
10-28 14:23:24.587 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/data/com.infasoftlanka.filter/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x42187db0
10-28 14:23:24.587 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.infasoftlanka.filter/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x42187db0, skipping init
10-28 14:23:24.587 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter V/RenderScript_jni: Unable to load libRSSupportIO.so, USAGE_IO not supported
10-28 14:23:24.587 5714-5750/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/RenderScript: Couldn't load libRSSupportIO.so
10-28 14:23:24.587 5714-5750/com.infasoftlanka.filter V/RenderScript: 0x4e88d008 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
10-28 14:23:24.592 5714-5750/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library (/data/data/com.infasoftlanka.filter//lib/librs.color.so): Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library 'libRSSupportIO.so' not found
10-28 14:23:24.592 5714-5750/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/RenderScript: Unable to open system shared library (/system/lib/librs.color.so): (null)
10-28 14:23:24.592 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-28 14:23:24.592 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417232a0)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infasoftlanka.filter/com.infasoftlanka.filter.MainActivity}: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:61)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rsdemo.ScriptC_color.<init>(ScriptC_color.java:42)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.infasoftlanka.filter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
10-28 14:23:24.597 5714-5714/com.infasoftlanka.filter E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-28 14:23:28.172 5714-5714/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5714 SIG: 9
```

Mainactivity.java Crashing here:

```
    'ScriptC_color color = new ScriptC_color (mRS, getResources (), R.raw.color);'
```

My gradle file

```
    '
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.infasoftlanka.filter"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        renderscriptDebuggable true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')
}
'
```

Comment: Provide a color resource named `action_bar_background`. Problem solved.

Comment: you need to mention:

<color name="action_bar_background">any hex code you want</color>

in res > values > colors.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Build-Tools 23.0.3?

Also, try replace

```
ScriptC_color color = new ScriptC_color (mRS, getResources (), R.raw.color);
```

with

```
ScriptC_color color = new ScriptC_color (mRS);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add this line in proguard-rules.pro -

-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** {*;}

and remove this line-
compile files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')